# Vary dbPool user based on session$clientData$hostname (i.e. local or not local)

Tags: r, shiny, database-connection, pool, dbplyr

Oftentimes when developing Shiny apps that connect to databases it's necessary to work with different usernames when the app is local/on server.

The `pool` approach to database connections is the most efficient (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-dplyr.html) but invoking a connection to the database outside of the `shinyServer` function [as recommended] means that one cannot use `session$clientData$url_hostname`

I would like to make a shiny app that achieves the following:

- Initiates a db pool with the username decided by if the app is running on 127.0.0.1 or not
- Display rows_to_show rows of the table, with rows_to_show set by a `sliderInput`

A method that uses rsconnet() to run/deploy the app would be sufficient.

```
## ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sliderInput(
    "rows_to_show",
    "Exponent",
    min = 10,
    max = 50,
    value = 5
  ),
  dataTableOutput("table")
))


## server.R
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")
library("dbplyr")
library("pool")
library("RMySQL")
## tryCatch so the app will actually run
tryCatch(
  the_db <- dbPool(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = "the_db",
    port = 3306,
    host = "163.1.169.xxx",
    user = "database_username" 
  ),
  error = function(e)
    e
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  database_username <- eventReactive(input$exponent,
                                     {
                                       if (session$clientData$url_hostname == "127.0.0.1") {
                                         "local_username"
                                       } else {
                                         "remote_username"
                                       }
                                     }, ignoreInit = FALSE)


  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    rows_to_show <- as.numeric(input$rows_to_show)

    # the_db %>%
    #   tbl("my_table") %>%
    #   collect() %>%
    #   slice(1:rows_to_show)
    iris %>%
      slice(1:rows_to_show)

  })

})
```

Comment: I'm encountering this exact situation. I need to vary the hostname depending on where the app is deployed (we're deploying apps to dev, stage, and prod). In addition, at some point in the future, we'll also need to pass sql creds based on the user accessing the app. @Martin, have you figured it out?